# Can HAML in Ruby on Rails output HTML attributes in an "ordered hash" way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

For example, if using haml:

```
%html{'xmlns' => "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml",
      'xmlns:og' => "http://ogp.me/ns#",
      'xmlns:fb' => "http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"}
```

the output is:

```
<html xmlns:fb='http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml' xmlns:og='http://ogp.me/ns#' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
```

which is in a different order.  Is there a way to make it in the order that was specified?

(it is using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.6)

**Update 1:** although in HTML, the attributes' order doesn't matter, but in some case, I just want to follow what the spec says.  Who knows what their parser does and whether it uses some regular-expression to do things that people following the spec will match, but not following the spec will not match, because of the "bug" that they use regular-expression to do parsing.

**Update 2:** Or, what if in the general case for something else?  It doesn't need to be HTML attributes.  It can be anything of which order is important.

Comment: Uh... why would you need this?  As Marc-Andre below points out, attributes in html elements are orderless.

Answer (score 4):

I'll point out that arguments in HTML are orderless, so it is quite unclear why you would care about this.

<strike>If you really want to keep the order, you could use the alternate HAML syntax:</strike>

```
%html(xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
  xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml")
```

Edit: alternate syntax gives same result. `goto "arguments_are_orderless"`

Comment: "Be liberal in what you accept, and conservative in what you send." (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle).

There are a lot of crappy parsers out there in the real world, doing ridiculous things like reading XML character-by-character (no DOM/SAX). Sometimes you just have to replicate a format whether it's The Right Thing or not.

Answer (score 2):

You could, if you generate the actual HTML string yourself from a helper function.

```
def html_with_ns
  '<html xmlns="...">'
end
```

and then

```
=html_with_ns
```

in the template. Not very attractive, but perhaps that's the price for perfection in this case.

You could argue that this should not be necessary since hashes are actually ordered in Ruby 1.9 (see comments below, I didn't know this was the case). Perhaps a patch for Haml to not sort hashes when running under 1.9 might be in order...

Comment: I thought there is ordered hash... can that be used?  also, if using helper, then I may as well use a `:plain`

Comment: Hashes are ordered in 1.9 IIRC. See [this post](http://www.igvita.com/2009/02/04/ruby-19-internals-ordered-hash/).

Comment: @Brandon Interesting. I withdraw the "you can't".

Comment: Yep, they're ordered in 1.9.2. Is haml alphabetizing or printing them in reverse order?

Comment: I got a chuckle out of "might be *in order*," even if it was not intended. :)

Comment: @kshep Version 3.1.1 (that i have lying around) sorts. The test cases imply this, but don't specifically check for it (that I can see).

Comment: Haven't tested the theory, but perhaps [this is the offending line](https://github.com/nex3/haml/blob/5f04bbda570a41acfb1/lib/haml/compiler.rb#L396)?

Comment: @Brandon, that's the same one I found anyway. :)